# How to handle run time exceptions thrown by Spring Security AuthenticationProviders?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, exception

How to handle runtime exceptions thrown by Spring Security Authentication Providers ? I'm using Spring Boot 1.4.2 but I feel like this applies also to classic Spring applications.

Let's say I have an `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` configured to authenticate users against my corporate AD. It all works nice with Spring Security when the authentication fails due to bad credentials (an  `AuthenticationException` is thrown which is properly handled by the Spring Security mechanism = the app goes back to the login screen and the authentication error can be shown).

However it so happens that sometimes, the AD is down temporarily and a `org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException` is thrown instead. This exception is a runtime exception and therefore isn't trapped by Spring's security mechanism because it doesn't extend `AuthenticationException`.

What happens in this case, is that the app is redirected to the default error page (which is /error). What I want to do, is to still show the login screen with a custom message.

I've found that I can do that, if I create something like

```
public class ActiveDirectoryLdapExtendedAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

private final ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adAuthenticationProvider;

public ActiveDirectoryLdapExtendedAuthenticationProvider(ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider adAuthenticationProvider) {
    this.adAuthenticationProvider = adAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication a) throws AuthenticationException {

    Authentication auth = null;

    try {            
        auth = adAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(a);
    }
    catch(CommunicationException communicationException) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Could not reach User Directory. Please try again in a few minutes");
    }

    return auth;
}
```

This works but I feel that there must be a better way.

I've tried creating a `ControllerAdvice` annotated class but it doesn't get called by the POST to login by Spring Security. I would imagine that it's because POST is handled by Spring Security filters, which being Servlet filters, sit above the main Spring MVC dispatcher servlet.

I've also tried to create a `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` to handle a `CommunicationException` and redirect to the login page, but that doesn't work either as my `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` doesn't get called either.

The other workaround that I've come up with is to tackle the exception at the error page itself, something like (using Thymeleaf)

```
<div class="container error" th:switch="${exception}">
        <span  th:case="'org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException'">Error communicating with User Directory. Please try again in a few minutes</span>
        <span  th:case="*">An unexpected error has occurred</span>
</div>
```

I still feel like there should be a better way. How can I configure the DispatcherServlet to ensure that a CommunicationException is to be redirected to the /login controller, and not the error page ? Or more generically... how can I configure that any exception at the login stage, is shown on the login screen ?

Comment: You cannot... It is a `Filter` and a `Filter` is always executed before a `Servlet` (this is defined in the servlet specification). So the `DispatcherServlet` cannot do anything about it. You can specify what to do on specific exceptions in the container (you need to modify your embedded tomcat configuration for that).

Comment: @M.Deinum I see.. the part where you can map specific error codes or exception types to paths. Personally, I was looking for something a bit more customizable, like - if the exception happens at the login screen, always display the error on the login screen, but not otherwise. This means I would have to map to an MVC view to check the Authentication in session and perform this logic - if authenticated go to default error page, otherwise go to default login. Maybe my rationale is flawed and an unexpected error should always go to a well defined error page

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same problem and solved it creating custom Spring [AuthenticationFailureHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949665/spring-custom-authenticationfailurehandler). It caught error by throwing BadCredentialsException in custom [AuthenticationProvider](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider)  class.